# Child marriage today

Tags: marriage, wedding, children

Suppose that in their infinite pubescent wisdom, a 12-year-old girl and a 13-year-old boy decided that they wanted to get married, somehow acquired a kosher ring and witnesses, performed kiddushin, and then refused to give or receive a *get*.

Could their parents and/or school principal get the marriage invalidated without their cooperation? If not, would they have any obligations to each other? How should such a couple conduct themselves?

(As always, CYLOR.)

Comment: If they performed Kiddushin, the parents have no ability to annul it. They'd be fully married.

Comment: Why should anyone invalidate it? If either party ever wants out, they can do a Get then.  Also why would there be any obligations after only Kiddushin?

Comment: What does a "kosher ring" mean?  Just that it's not made out of an idol, cheeseburger, kilei hakerem, etc.?

Comment: Picture asking this question 2000 years ago; its the same.

Comment: Note that this has happened quite a bit. There are several teshuvos in Igros Moshe and others describing how to deal with cases where teens 'joke around' and some people end up (at the very least a Safek) married. That's a powerful line normally said under the Chuppah, you don't mess around with it.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: @Heshy A ring worth a prutah that belongs to the boy. Very likely the ring won’t belong to the boy, which is a great way to invalidate the marriage.

Comment: @LN6595 that makes a lot of sense, I didn't think of that.  (Unless.. might it be a problem if he had permission to use it, and he's giving her permission to wear it for a short time, and that's worth a prutah?)

Comment: @LN6595 why does it have to be a ring? It could be anything that's worth a prutah (aprox ¢3) that shouldn't be hard for a 13 year old to obtain

Comment: @aBochur Complicated issue, not for here, but the boy’s possessions may in truth belong to his father.

Answer (score 7):

A boy at the age of 13, and a girl at the age of 12, who have fully matured according to halacha, (as explained in [Rambam Sefer Nashim Hilcos Ishus perek 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Marriage.2.1?with=all&lang=bi)) are considered adults according to halacha.

So as long as the *kedushin* and *nissuin* were done according to the basic guidelines, there is nothing others can do to break them up, other than getting the boy to give a *get.*

> If not, would they have any obligations to each other?

They would have the regular obligations as any other jewish couple have to each other.

Comment: What about Nissuin? What about Sa'arot? What about getting her to accept the get? How do you know any of this?

Comment: @doubleaa i added nissuin. As for the rest of it, I wrote that as long as it was done with the basic guidelines, they are fully married. That includes saarot and her accepting it. Had the question been about what goes into a kosher nissuin, i would obviously have to add more details. As for a source, I'll add one soon.

Comment: Then why do you leave in your patently false opening sentence???